# Where can I find a list of .NET unicode (wide) functions?

Tags: vb.net, unicode, function

I would like to get a list of the VB.net/C# "wide" functions for unicode - i.e. AscW, ChrW, MessageBoxW, etc.

Is there a list of these somewhere?

Comment: In VB.NET, Asc and AscW are the same call, the same with Chr and ChrW. They are interchangeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All string methods in .NET are Unicode by default.  .NET uses unicode strings for all String methods, since [System.String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) is Unicode.

From [System.String's Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx):

> Represents text as a series of Unicode characters.

Any time you call any method that takes a String as a parameter, you're working in Unicode.  There is no need for "wide character" versions of methods in .NET.

---

In fact, if you want to work with ANSI text, you need to explicitly tell the framework that is what you are doing.

This is often used via a method from the [Marhsal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringansi.aspx) class (for interop with other libraries), or via the [Encoding class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) ([Encoding.ASCII](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx), or a different character encoding) to convert a series of bytes to or from text.

Comment: +1, a better question is "where are the ASCII string functions?" :)

Answer (score 1):

All .net strings are Unicode already.  There are no Ascii strings to worry about.  So they dropped the W from the Win32 names.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in .net are all Unicode. You don't need specific functions to handle Unicode because it's built in already.